# async eachLimit and whilst RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, node-async

I have an script that looks for hotels without image size in the DB, then test a couple of dimensions making a request to that image and assign it to the hotel if it finds it, but I can't understand why I'm getting this error.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Here is the code: (The SQL query return 100k rows)

```
  async.waterfall([
    function(cb) {
      console.log('-- start --');
      connection.query('SELECT id,image_url FROM hotels WHERE image_size IS NULL', function(err, hotels) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        return cb(null, hotels);
      });
    },
    function(hotels, cb) {
      var success = 0;
      async.eachLimit(hotels, 10, function(hotel, callback) {
        var flag  = false;
        var test  = ['_w.jpg','_z.jpg','_y.jpg', '_b.jpg'];
        var index = 0;
        var url   = hotel.image_url;
        var size  = '0';
        async.whilst(function() {
          return flag === false && index <= test.length
        }, function(while_callback) {
            if (!hotel.image_url) return while_callback();
            var current_url = hotel.image_url.replace('_b.jpg', test[index]);
            request.get(current_url, function(err, res, body) {
              index += 1;
              if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                flag = true;
                url  = current_url;
                size = current_url.match(/[wzyb]/).toString();
                success += 1;
              }
              return while_callback();
            });
          }, function(err, n) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            connection.query('UPDATE hoteles SET ? WHERE ?', [{ image_url: url, image_size: size }, { id: hotel.id }], function(err, result) {
              if (err) return callback(err);
              console.log(hotel.id, size, success)
              return callback();
            });
          });
      }, function(err) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        console.log('-- done --');
        return cb();
      });
    }], function(err, result) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      return console.log(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is synchronous which means you're doing recursions.

```
if (!hotel.image_url) return while_callback();
```

replace with

```
if (!hotel.image_url) return process.nextTick(while_callback);
```